# Firefox session development issue

Tags: php, html, firefox

My website under development has a weird issue.
once logged in, the user is redirected to read the license agreement. In this page called `terms.php` I conditionaly show a confirm button that redirects the user to a page called `agreed.php` if the user is logged in, and else: to `register.php`.

The weird thing is only in Firefox (has firebug installed).
once logged in, the `terms.php`'s form is showing `action="register.php"`  ! instead of `agreed.php`, and all checks I made show that the user is NOT logged in.
Another weird thing, is if I hit F5 to refresh, It shows `agreed.php`! 
It doesn't happen in IE nor in Chrome.

Any idea what this might be ?

```
function logged_in() {
    return isset($_SESSION['USER_ID']);
}

function redirect_to( $location = NULL) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
    }
}
```

**login.php**

```
if (shouldReadTerms())
    redirect_to("terms.php");
```

**terms.php**

```
    <?php if(logged_in()): ?> 
    <?php if (shouldReadTerms()): ?>
        <form action="agreed.php" method="POST">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button <?php if (!shouldReadTerms()) echo 'disabled'; ?>>I Agree </button>
    <?php if (shouldReadTerms()): ?>
        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br />
    <br />
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <br />
    <br />
    <button>I Agree</button>
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `Any idea what this might be?` - Not without seeing some code.

Comment: Hi Ted, please can you post the code

Answer (score 2):

This bug can be two reasons. Session and cache.

If you are confident that the problem only in FF for the start delete cookies and clear the browser cache.

If this does not help add to `terms.php`

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

If this also does not help try to see a dump of the session at each step after authorization.

Comment: I changed my session.php to contain that header line. It DID the trick. Once I put that line inside the terms.php, the bug remains. Which makes me think that maybe it has something to do with the previous page... I am not sure if putting this line for all my pages would be a good idea (I assume cache does speed up things...) but I am not sure I completely understand the meaning of putting this line. could you please advise?

Comment: This header prohibits the use of a cached version of the page that is declared. Use it on all pages is not good. Sending a header from terms.php may not work if the data which have been sent before. Try to send a header from session.php but only on this page to test this idea.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't an issue in IE or Chrome you could try

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
```

in the header on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Sad but true:
changed:

```
redirect_to("terms.php");
```

to

```
redirect_to("terms.php?".rand());
```

Problem solved. 
Although not 100% sure of why. But it works like a charm for now